# Login automatically after registration using tank_auth for codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

After reading a lot of answers here on what is the best authentication out there for codeigniter, I decided to use [tank_auth](http://konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/).

It seems to be the best authentication for codeigniter.

However, I have some few questions regarding on how I can integrate it successfully on my site. I am currently building a hotel reservation system. So some functionality of tank_auth needs to be modified to suit my needs.

So how can I, after registration, login the user automatically without requiring him/her to activate his/her account. Is there a configuration to disable the "activation process". If yes, where can I find it? If no, is it a big modification to the code if I remove the activation process?

On the auth.php code I tried to comment the following code to remove the activation process but seems it does not work:

```
} elseif ($this->tank_auth->is_logged_in(FALSE)) { // logged in, not activated
redirect('/auth/send_again/');
```

Answer (score 1):

That code only works when the user account exists but is not activated. it then resends an activation email...

Look at the register part of the library and set the login session parameters to be true ie parameters that sets login to be true and then direct to the protected area!